# What are os.fdopen() semantics?

Tags: python, linux, macos, python-2.7

I used to think that `os.fdopen()` either eats file descriptor and returns a file io object, or raises an exception.

For example:

```
fd = os.open("/etc/passwd", os.O_RDONLY)
try: os.fdopen(fd, "w")
except: os.close(fd)  # prevent memory leak
```

However these semantics don't seem to always hold.

Here's an example on OSX:

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: os.open("/", os.O_RDONLY, 0660)
Out[2]: 5

In [3]: os.fdopen(5, "rb")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-3ca4d619250e> in <module>()
----> 1 os.fdopen(5, "rb")

IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '<fdopen>'

In [4]: os.close(5)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-76713e571514> in <module>()
----> 1 os.close(5)

OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

It seems that `os.fdopen()` both ate my file descriptor `5` and raised an exception...

Is there a safe way to use `os.fdopen()`?

Did I miss something?

Did I find a bug?

P.S. Python version string `Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54)` in case someone can't reproduce with theirs.

P.P.S. same problem is present on Py2.7 Linux too.
Py3.3 however doesn't exhibit said problem.

Comment: Well, I really don't understnad what is unclear. On OS level you may open a directory as it was a file and try to read it (although `opendir` & `readdir` does the job better). Although Python files are files indeed so when you try to create a file object on a file directory descriptor it breaks with the exception. That's it

Comment: Question is if `os.fdopen` is allowed to consume file descriptor without returning file object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python checks that the resulting `FILE*` does not refer to a directory after creating the python file object and storing it in the python object. Because of the error in the directory check, the file object is deref'd (since it won't be returned) which causes the destructor to be called which closes the file.

I agree that it'd be nice if the docs showed what effect it can have on the file descriptor passed in. I'm not sure what you want as a 'safe' way to use fdopen. If you're going to close the filedescriptor on failure, what does it matter that was closed by python? Just use

```
try: os.close(fd)
except: pass
```

to quelch the secondary exception.

[`fill_file_fields`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d08e3586dde3/Objects/fileobject.c#l141) is called by [`PyFile_FromFile`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d08e3586dde3/Objects/fileobject.c#l469) to fill in the members of the file object and it calls the [`dircheck`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d08e3586dde3/Objects/fileobject.c#l120) function after the fields have been populated. This causes `fill_file_fields` to return NULL so [`PyFile_FromFile` does `Py_DECREF(f);`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d08e3586dde3/Objects/fileobject.c#l485) where `f` is the file object. Since this is the last reference, the deallocator [`file_dealloc`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d08e3586dde3/Objects/fileobject.c#l614) is called which invokes [`close_the_file`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d08e3586dde3/Objects/fileobject.c#l421) which (surprise, surprise) closes the file.

In the 3.4 branch, the dircheck is done from [`fileio_init`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5e303360db14/Modules/_io/fileio.c#l214) which uses the flag variable `fd_is_own` to determine whether the file should be closed on an error condition.

Comment: Good explanation. Your `try/except` however is not safe. If `fdopen` quietly closed `fd` and another action (e.g. thread or logging) created a file descriptor, this other file descriptor will have same number and you inadvertently close it instead.

Comment: Can you point me to the actual location in CPython source code where *file object is deref'd*?